# AspectJ aspect is not being intercepted if @Cacheble Spring AOP applied on the same function

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, ehcache, spring-aop

I have defined two aspects on a function of a @Controller class.

One is @Cacheble (Ehcache Spring annotation, which uses Spring AOP).

Another one is an around advice that compute the execution time. This is an AspectJ Compile Time aspect.

When the method is called for the first time, both of the aspect is being executed. But, for all the subsequent call, only @Cacheble aspect is intercepted. Another advice (that computes execution time) is not being intercepted. Why is this not being intercepted? 
I've set @Order for both aspects, but that doesn't help.

The second aspect that computes execution time is as following

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Order(value = 0)
public @interface MonitorPerformance {   
}
```

Dispathcher-servlet.xml has
`<ehcache:annotation-driven create-missing-caches="true" 
                               cache-manager="ehCacheManager"
                               order="1"/>`
Looking forward to your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed this does sound like an order of aspects problem. How have you defined the order? Can you show code/XML? Have you tried switching the order between them?

Comment: The question now has the code. I tried @order. This doesn't help. Can this problem be due to mixing Spring AOP and AspectJ

Answer (score 0):

For aspects to execute, you must call your method on the instance that you acquired from the container. Is it the case?

Comment: Yes, the method handles URL request in a Controller class. For the first time, when the method is executed, both of the aspect is being intercepted. For for the subsequent call, only Cacheble is intercepted. I suppose, if it hits cache, the method is not being called. So, the Around advice (that calculates execution time) is not being called. But, I want to monitor the time even if cache hit occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi if this is is compile time AspectJ with spring AOP then it wont execute the compiled aspect on the cached result. The bytecode for compiled classes is injected directly around the method. If this is proxied and returned without ever calling the method (which is what cacheable does) then, naturally, the latter aspect wont be called.